# Present Simple Usage in these sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, present-tense, present-simple

I am confused about the usage of Present Simple in these sentence.

1. Sorry in advance to anyone whose name i **pronounce** wrong.

You can assume that he is just telling a fact but it is said in an particular youtube video.

I think **"pronounced"** should be used instead of **"pronounce"**. Why the present simple is used in these sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In advance" implies that the errro, if it happens is in the future. The simple present is often used for future events.

However, I believe this would be more correct as :

> - I want to say "Sorry" in advance to anyone whose name I pronounce wrongly.
> - I apologize in advance to anyone whose name I pronounce wrongly.

If the possible erro has already occured, this could be:

> I want to say "Sorry"  to anyone whose name I pronounced wrongly.

One could use "mispronounce" instead of "pronounce wrongly". It is less formal.

Comment: So does that mean " If i pronounce wrongly, then I want to say sorry" is it right?

Comment: Also, is that sentence valid if i dont use "in advance"?

Comment: @lollel123 That would be  "If i pronounce a name wrongly, then I want to say I'm sorry". One does not say "If I pronounce wrongly" without an object such as "a name" or "a word". In person, "in advance" would be obvious and could be left out. In writing it helps make it clear that this is said **before** the possible error.

Comment: "Sorry to anyone whose name i pronounce wrong" doesn"t sound natural to me.

Comment: Maybe these are correct "Sorry to anyone whose name i pronounce wrong in these video" or "Sorry to anyone whose name I am  pronouncing wrong"

Comment: I used the present continuous to refer to future.

Comment: @lollel123 please read the examples in the answer. "pronounce wrong" is not natural, it should be  "pronounce wrong**ly**" or better "mispronounce". The sentence should not start just ":sorry to"  bu "I want to say sorry to" ,or "I want to apologize to"

Comment: I understand. But can you tell me whether my 2 examples are right?

Comment: So "pronounce" is referring to the future, right?

Comment: "Sorry to anyone whose name i pronounce wrong" is not good, It might be ok in VERY informal speech, "Sorry to anyone whose name I am pronouncing wrong"  is better, although I would still favor "mispronouncing".

Comment: Thanks for relieving my confusion. Turns out that I was confused because of present simple referring to future but now I know present simple can be used to refer to the future!

Comment: @lollel123 "pronounce" could be in the present or the future, in your original; example it seem to be the future. "pronounced" would be the past.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the simple present is correct here.  He is speaking of a general fact that remains true:

> Grass is green.
>   Nadal plays tennis.
>   I pronounce some names wrong.

He is saying this is not a particular mistake he might make in the future,or have made in the past. Instead it is a general failure of his to speak (foreign) names correctly.  As it is a general fact, the simple present is possible.